# Genexus Server, como tratar múltiplas instâncias dele

Tags: genexus

Gostaríamos de trabalhar com uma `KB` no `GXServer X Ev2 U5` com um backup nosso do `GXServer Ev2 U2`.

Como devemos tratar isto a nível de backup / operacionalização?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No documento que está no wiki no link a seguir, explica como ter múltiplas instâncias do GXServer:

[http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?GeneXus+Server+multi-instance+installation,](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?GeneXus%20Server%20multi-instance%20installation,)

Ou seja, você vai poder instalar o GXServer da X Ev2U5 em outra URL, deverá configurar outras bases de dados e é melhor configurar um POOL diferente.

Para fazer a migração da KB de uma versão do server para outro server, olhar o seguinte link:

[http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Migrating+a+KB+between+GXserver+instances,](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Migrating%20a%20KB%20between%20GXserver%20instances,)